# Simplest way to use Powershell 7 on Windows to set ownership and permissions on files and directories?

Tags: powershell, permissions, ownership

Assume I have a directory somedir that contains several files somefile_nn.txt
The directory and files are currently owned by john, and have full permissions for Everyone which it inherited from parentdir. I want to change the directory and files to be owned by mary, readable only by mary, and have no permissions for anyone else.
On Linux this would look like:

```
sudo chown -R mary somedir
sudo chmod 700 somedir
sudo chmod 600 somedir/*.txt
```

So far, my internet searches on how to do this with Powershell 7 on Windows have not gone well. The best I’ve found are rather complicated. What is the current simplest way to set ownership and permissions on files and directories?

Thanks!

Comment: PS console/ISE/VSCode, etc., allows one to use raw PS/.Net libs for all that is possible, and it allows the running of any executable (as long as you pass it all the points it requires.). PSv7 notwithstanding, the ability to change ownership would be the same. Don't look for PSv7 specifically, just PS in general. ['PowerShell change ownership recursively'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+change+ownership+recursively%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Comment: Do you want to do this with PowerShell-internal commands only? What you're asking is fairly easy to do using the standard icacls.exe, but it sounds like you're specifically excluding that?

Answer (score 2):

I also don't like the standard [Microsoft.PowerShell.Security](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/?view=powershell-7.2) module that is shipped with PowerShell and all of this `Get-Acl`, `Set-Acl` stuff.

I like to use the [NTFSSecurity](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/NTFSSecurity/4.2.6) Module. You can install that with `Install-Module NTFSSecurity`

The following commented sequence of code does the trick. You have to run them in an elevated PowerShell. I'd suggest to backup your folder first.

```
# Create a Test Folder
PS C:\install> mkdir testacl > $null

# Set the desired Owner
PS C:\install> Set-NTFSOwner testacl MyAccount

# Clear all NTFS Access and also the Inheritance from the folder above
PS C:\install> Clear-NTFSAccess testacl -DisableInheritance

# Add read access for my account
PS C:\install> Add-NTFSAccess testacl MyAccount Read
```

Now only `MyAccount` has read access for this folder and all its subfolders/files. Since Windows by default blocks any access that isn't specifically allowed, you don't have to do anything else.

We can check this like so:

```
PS C:\install> Get-NTFSAccess testacl

    Path: C:\install\testacl (Inheritance disabled)


Account                             Access Rights  Applies to                Type           IsInherited   InheritedFrom
-------                             -------------  ----------                ----           -----------   -------------
DESKTOP-ABCDEFG\MyAccount           Read, Synchro… ThisFolderSubfoldersAndF… Allow          False

PS C:\install> Get-NTFSOwner testacl

Item               Owner                     Account              FullName
----               -----                     -------              --------
C:\install\testacl DESKTOP-ABCDEFG\MyAccount DESKTOP-ABCDEFG\MyAccount C:\install\testacl
```

Run `Get-Help Add-NTFSAccess` to see what AccessRights you can specify. Or [read the docs](https://ntfssecurity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment and the pointer from it.

One can run any DOS/Cmd.exe executable from PS (any version) as well.

[PowerShell- Running Executables - TechNet Articles - United States (English) - TechNet Wiki](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)

> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024(v=ws.10).aspx

```
takeown /f "c:\folder\subfolder" /r
```

Using pure PS does sometimes require more code, by design. Sometimes fallback (using built-in executables) is more prudent.

Point of note, get real familiar with the addon modules from the MSPowerShellGallery

```
Find-Module -Name 'NTFSSecurity'
# Results
<#
Version              Name                                Repository           Description                                                                              
-------              ----                                ----------           -----------                                                                              
4.2.6                NTFSSecurity                        PSGallery            Windows PowerShell Module for managing file and folder security on NTFS volumes 
#>
```